# Avoid multiple AsyncTask when calling Autocomplete google places

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I am using a text watcher to show the user a list of google places predictions, each time the user types a character, the asyncTask starts to get the new prediction, but when the user types too fast, all asyncTasks are triggered and will show multiple laggy results.

My question here, can i cancel old asyncTasks and only trigger the one with the last typed character?

Comment: Can you show us the current code you're using? We can then advise for changes based on that. But basically you just need to keep a reference of the latest `AsyncTask` and call `cancel()` before you start a new one.

Comment: Thank you @torque203 .. i posted a code with the correct implementation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally managed to make the correct answer .. thanks @torque203

I initialized Google Places AsyncTask method in the beginning of the class as following

```
private GooglePlaces GP = null;
```

and then ..

```
if (GP != null) {
        GP.cancel(true);
        GP = new GooglePlaces();
        GP.execute(sb.toString());
    } else {
        GP = new GooglePlaces();
        GP.execute(sb.toString());
    }
```